# How to prevent the froala editor to format my code view html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, froala

i am using froala editor, however when i put this html code in the code view

```
<td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/GSCinemas/videos/10155007044777275/" target="_blank"><img src="http://edm.gsc.com.my/WebLITE/Applications/campaignmgmt/uploaded/pics/2017/gsc-edm-july2017/masthead-gsc30.jpg" width="280" height="110" alt="#GSC30" title="#GSC30" class="img-max" style="display:block;"></a></td>
```

it become,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body style="min-height: 300px;">

        <p>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/GSCinemas/videos/10155007044777275/" target="_blank"><img src="http://edm.gsc.com.my/WebLITE/Applications/campaignmgmt/uploaded/pics/2017/gsc-edm-july2017/masthead-gsc30.jpg" width="280" height="110" alt="#GSC30" title="#GSC30" class="img-max fr-fil fr-dib"></a>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

i dont want it to help me to format anything, how can i disable the froala editor to format anything for me?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the `fullPage` option: https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options#fullPage. When this option is used, the editor is automatically adding `HTML`, `HEAD` and `BODY` tags.

To disable wrapping the `a` with `P` tags, you should also turn the `enter` option to `$.FroalaEditor.ENTER_BR`: https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options#enter.

Comment: thanks for help , the currently froala 'must' format our thing, the maximum we can do is enable full page option